# Convert "String Object" to Object

Tags: javascript

i have problem,
I have strings like "[prop1][prop2][prop3] = 5" ..and i need convert this string to JS object, so created object willl looks like this:

```
{
 prop1: {
  prop2: {
   prop3: 5
  }
 }
}
```

Any help? thanks

Comment: Convert to JSON string and than JSON.parse() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: What have you found out so far? Where are you stuck? You must have tried *something* before asking this question.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Splitting the string and looping over its parts shouldn't be too complicated

Comment: @Cheery: I don't see any JSON anywhere in this question, so this is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not mention all the specifics of the data (how many levels, type of the data and so on), so...

```
var str = '[prop1][prop2][prop3] = 5'
          .replace(/\[/g, '{"')
          .replace(/\]/g, '":')
          .replace('=', '');
console.log(JSON.parse(str + '}}}'));
```

Mod for any number of levels

```
var str = '[prop1][prop2][prop3] = 5';
var opens = str.match(/\[/g).length,
    str = str.replace(/\[/g, '{"')
             .replace(/\]/g, '":')
             .replace('=', '');
console.log(JSON.parse(str + (new Array(opens + 1).join('}'))));
```